# How do I create a filter for Microsoft Excel?

Tags: c++, excel

I want to add a file type extension to the Open Dialog of Excel (2003, 2007 if possible, 2007 only, if necessary).

When the user opens my type of file (i.e. myfile.myx), I want my application to read the file and paste the file into Excel in my own defined manner (by using Interop)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are out of luck here. There is no documented way of extending Excel with custom import filter (as far as I know). Such a converter interface only exists for Word (http://support.microsoft.com/kb/111716).

If you want to modify the file open dialog you could try to subclass the dialog. This works for the Windows Common Dialogs (see http://www.codeproject.com/KB/dialog/customize_dialog.aspx for an example), but I suppose the Office dialogs use different messages and may not allow what you want to do.